# Is IEnumerable required to use a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, foreach

I was wondering, when exactly can I use the foreach loop? Do I have to implement IEnumerable?

Comment: [1st answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ttw7t8t6%28VS.80%29.aspx) at Google.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb8xew9(VS.80).aspx

Comment: You can use them on Tuesdays and Thursdays and during the fifth weekend of a calendar month.

Comment: You can use it any time, any place.. as long as you do not misuse it, I guess.. otherwise the authorities won't be very happy.

Comment: `foreach(var complaint in new string[]{ "not ", "a ", "real ", "question!" }) Console.Write(complaint);`

Answer (score 39):

There is no need to implement the IEnumerable interface to use the foreach statement.  Here is a quote from the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb8xew9.aspx):

> In C#, it is not absolutely necessary
>   for a collection class to inherit from
>   IEnumerable and IEnumerator in order
>   to be compatible with foreach. As long
>   as the class has the required
>   GetEnumerator, MoveNext, Reset, and
>   Current members, it will work with
>   foreach. Omitting the interfaces has
>   the advantage of enabling you to
>   define the return type of Current to
>   be more specific than Object, which
>   provides type-safety.

Comment: Like this one because it correctly states that `IEnumerable` is *not* required. It certainly makes life easier, though.

Comment: That's really interesting, and I didn't know that. But I'd assume this was mainly to support type safety in .NET 1.0. I'd say the best way to ensure type safety nowadays is to use the generic version of IEnumerable.

Comment: +1 Learning something new every day.

Comment: Good point. I didn't know that either.

Comment: Does the foreach statement is a kind of syntactic sugar? Meaning, does the compiler complies it into a "regular" 'for' statement that uses GetEnumerator().MoveNext() and Current property?

Comment: @Josh: Yes, it is sugar. No, it's not turned into a `for` loop. See the language spec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can foreach though any object that implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumberable<T>`

Answer (score 2):

Comprehensive explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself - do you really need a loop counter

The rule of thumb I use is determining if I am moving data between two indexed containers, where I really do need an index value to address the destination, or more generally, 'do I need an index count for each item I am processing in the loop' ?  In those cases, I use a for loop, in pretty much all other cases (where foreach can deal with the container, which as noted above is pretty much every container) -  the reason is pretty simple, it looks pretty stupid to use foreach and then have to go to the trouble of manually maintaining a loop counter.