# C# foreach error

Tags: c#

```
string connection = "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbase + 
";User ID=" + userid + ";Password=" + password;

conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SUBNETTEMP", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Parameters d = new Parameters();
d.addparam(15, 1);
d.addparam(15, 2);

foreach (var param in d)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(param.Key, param.Value));
}
```

There's a class called parameters:

```
class Parameters
{
    Dictionary<int, int> paramids;
    public Dictionary<int, int> addparam(int sid, int sbid)
    {
        if (paramids == null)
            paramids = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        paramids.Add(sid, sbid);
        return paramids;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting error :"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ConsoleApplication1.Parameters' because 'ConsoleApplication1.Parameter' doesnot contain public definition for GetEnumerator.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not understandable? Do you know why `foreach` works on an array but not e.g. on a `DateTime`?

Comment: I don't see why you feel you need to define that class.  Why not just use a Dictionary directly?  Or better yet, add your parameters directly to the command?

Comment: I agree with Jeff. This class is most likely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Parameters` class would need to either inherit from `Dictionary`, or expose its inner dictionary to enumerate via `foreach`:

```
class Parameters {
    Dictionary<int, int> paramids;
    ....
    public Dictionary<int, int> ParamIDs {
        get { return paramids; }
    }
}
```

So now this would work:

```
foreach (var param in d.ParamIDs) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Parameters` class has no `GetEnumerator` method. Just like the error said.

You can either iterate over the `paramids` field, but for that you'd need to publicly expose it, which is a bad idea IMO.

The alternative is implementing `GetEnumerator`, forwarding it to `paramids.GetEnumerator`:

```
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int,int>> GetEnumerator()
{
    return paramids.GetEnumerator();
}
```

For good measure you should also add and implement the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,int>>` and `IEnumerable` interfaces, even if they're not necessary for a simple `foreach`.

---

As a side-note: I consider exposing the internal dictionary as the return value of `addparam` a dubious design choice. If you want a fluent API return your own instance of `Parameters`, and not the internal dictionary. I.e. use `return this`.

Also I'd use the .net naming conventions, so call your method `AddParam` not `addparam`.

---

So your complete class would be:

```
class Parameters:IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,int>>
{
    Dictionary<int, int> paramids;

    public Parameters AddParam(int sid, int sbid)
    {
        if (paramids == null)
            paramids = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        paramids.Add(sid, sbid);
        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int,int>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return paramids.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: hOw do we do that..actually I am new to C#...so dont know much about it.

Answer (score 1):

`Parameters` does not have a `GetEnumerator()?` method, which is what `foreach` relies on for looping over a collection. You should refactor out the `Parameters` class (it looks a bit over-crafted to have a separate class for that) and use a `Dictionary<>` directly.

An alternative is to have `Parameters` implement `GetEnumerator()`:

```
class Parameters
{
    Dictionary<int, int> paramids;
    public Dictionary<int, int> addparam(int sid, int sbid)
    {
        if (paramids == null)
            paramids = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        paramids.Add(sid, sbid);
        return paramids;
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, int>> GetEnumerator() 
    { 
        return paramids.GetEnumerator(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to implement the `IEnumerable` interface, having an accessible `GetEnumerator()` method that returns a `IEnumerator` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Thanks, didn't know that. SO of course has more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584351/is-ienumerable-required-to-use-a-foreach-loop/3584376#3584376

Comment: Implementing `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>>` is still a good idea. For example Linq does only work if you implement it. A (non legacy) class that has a `GetEnumerator()` but doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` sounds like a very dubious design choice to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your `Parameters` class as dictionary - inherit it from `Dictionary<int, int>`:

```
class Parameters: Dictionary<int, int>
{
}
```

but in this case maybe better to use just `Dictionary<int, int>`