# What happens in the foreach loop, which outputs the values of an array?

Tags: c#, class, foreach, iteration, ienumerable

I'm learning C and C#, this question is for C#. I have a instance of a class and I use a foreach loop to iterate through the values of "string[] days", but how does this happen? The class has a method which is GetEnumerator() and a array which is string[] days, but how does a instance of the class evaluate to the values of the string?

Here is the code:

```
static void Main()
{ 
    DaysOfTheWeek days = new DaysOfTheWeek();

    foreach (string day in days)
    {
        Console.Write(day + " ");
    }
    // Output: Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
    Console.ReadKey();
 }

public class DaysOfTheWeek : IEnumerable
{
    private string[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < days.Length; index++)
        {
            // Yield each day of the week. 
            yield return days[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? What do you mean, "how does it evaluate"?

Comment: @John I never call the GetEnumerator method, how does the foreach loop use the loop in the method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. But every instance you create comes with its own `string[] days` array. You just can't access it from *outside* because it's marked as `private`.

Comment: Does this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3584376/2530848. foreach will call `GetEnumerator` then it calls `MoveNext` on it and yields `Current`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DaysOfTheWeek` implements the interface [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you look at the[`foreach`-documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you see that foreach works with something that implements `IEnumerable` (technically it works with everything that has an appropriate GetEnumerator method, see comments below).

When you implement `IEnumerable` you basically promise, that you also implement a (public) method called `GetEnumerator`. Since the `foreach` knows that this method is there, it will use it to iterate  over/obtain your string values.

Comment: "If you look at theforeach-documentation, you see that foreach only works with something that implements IEnumerable."  This statement isn't technically correct.  Per the C# specification 8.8.4, you merely have to have a public `GetEnumerator()` function declared on your type - you don't specifically need the `IEnumerable` interface declaration for `foreach` to work.

Answer (score 1):

The foreach loop calls **automatically** the `GetEnumerator` method, which yields the days (strings).

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you do not have to write your own enumerator because every array (of ANY type) has an enumerator built in for you. So you would do:

```
public class DaysOfTheWeek : IEnumerable
{
    private string[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };

    foreach(var day in days){
        Console.WriteLine(day);
    }
}
```

Any class that implements the IEnumerable has a GetEnumerator() method, which returns a class that enumerates through the collection. The compiler translates the foreach loop for you using the Enumerator workflow. In short the compiler translates your code to something like:

```
private string[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
var enumerator = days.GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext()){
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```

Check out more about how enumerators work on the MSDN documentation.